# How to Implement Lazy Loading on a Large Number of Properties

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, lazy-loading, solution

I have a Class with multiple property-code like this snippet:

```
IFoo a;
public IFoo Foo
{
    get
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            // load a
            ...
        }
        return a;
    }
}


IBar b;
public IBar Bar
{
    get
    {
        if (b == null)
        {
            // load b
            ...
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

I have over 20 Propertys, where always the interface is different, not the loading-structure.
I feel this code is not optimal.

Is there a better solution? Maybe something generic, such as (not working):

```
T b;
public T Bar<T>
{
    get
    {
        if (b == null)
        {
            // load b
            ...
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're loading when the property getter is called, and not on instantiation?

Comment: @JonB It's called lazy loading.

Comment: I think this does not solve my problem. I have with these solutions multiple code, ie for example 20 propertys = 20 code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) construct which in fact is a syntactic sugar of your code.

Example from MSDN (define how to lazy load the object a a Func in the constructor, thread-safe):

```
lazyLargeObject = new Lazy<LargeObject>(() => 
{
    LargeObject large = new LargeObject(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    // Perform additional initialization here. 
    return large;
});
```

then the value will be fetched the first time you try to access the object like this:

```
LargeObject large = lazyLargeObject.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an implemenation of [Lazy Loading Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

There are some commons ways to get it done, like: Virtual Proxy, Value Holder and Ghost.
As @bjeger mentioned, you can use Lazy<T> to resolve your problem, but look and study the above implemenations will let you know what is better for your specific case.

Here is some samples using C#: [Four Ways to Implement Lazy Loading in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620215/Four-Ways-to-Implement-Lazy-Loading-in-Csharp).

Answer (score 0):

use [`LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642284%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.Threading;

IFoo a;
public IFoo Foo
{
    get
    {
        return LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref a, () => { /* load a */ });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get shorter properties at least is Lazy<T>:

```
Lazy<IBar> b = new Lazy<IBar>();
public IBar Bar
{
  get
  {
    return b.Value;
  }
}
```

When b.Value is first called it will call the default constructo of IBar. There are multiple overloads having to do with thread safety and calling other constructors. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx